# Hide all images, listings and equations?

Tags: equations, listings, preamble

is there any way to hide all images, equations and all listings (embedded by using lstlisting package) manually by setting a certain command in the preamble? It would just be interesting to see how many pages of real 'text' the document contains actually.
Thanks!

**Edit**:
I tried using Stefans suggestion:

```
\renewenvironment{lstlisting}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}
\renewenvironment{figure}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}
\renewenvironment{equation}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}
```

whereas I have the verbatim-package in the preamble. I'm getting the same error message as if when using Martins suggestion:

```
File ended while scanning use of \next for a command line `\include{main/02}`
```

When not using the commenting-stuff, there's no error while compiling the document :(

**Edit2**:
I found out that Martins solution works but not for equations which I insert via:

```
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
```

and than:

```
\beq
blaaa...
\eeq
```

Which way to take therefor?

Comment: Placing the `comment` environment into another environment doesn't work, like for any verbatim environment, because `\begin{comment}` then can't find it's `\end{comment}`. My small example works, but I can't say what's goes wrong with your file. You don't have an environment split over two input files, or something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `comment` package to turn an environment, even an existing one, into a comment environment. It skips the content verbatim so it can also be used for `lstlistings`, etc. However, it seems the `\end{<env>}` (actually the internal `\end<env>`) is still executed, so you need to blank that too.  For macros you need to define dummy replacements with the same set of arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}

\excludecomment{figure}
\let\endfigure\relax
\excludecomment{equation}
\let\endequation\relax
\excludecomment{lstlisting}
\let\endlstlisting\relax

% Also possible:
%\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{}
%\renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}[2][]{}

% For your funny equation marks use: (you then actually don't need to redefine `equation` itself)
\let\beq\iffalse
\let\eeq\fi
% or
% \def\beq#1\eeq{}

\begin{document}

Normal text

\begin{figure}
    (A figure)
    \caption{A figure indeed}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
  1+1=2
\end{equation}

\beq
  1+1=2
\eeq

\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited my answer above Martin :)

Comment: @Marc: The `\beq` and `\eeq` macros also hide the `equation` end-macro. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine all those environments and commands to do nothing, using `\renewenvironment`. Of course this can be summarized in one macro.

Comment: How can I redefine the figure command to do nothing?  Martin's answer doesn't work for me.