# Comment out `lstinputlisting` without actually removing them

Tags: listings, tex-general

I am wondering is there a way to hide or comment out all `lstinputlisting` from latex without actually removing them.

My codes are all like this:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, caption=NewHope implemented using SageMath]{code_snippets/LWE-KEX/NewHope.sage}
```

I tried to use comment package it [as suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/hide-all-images-listings-and-equations) and also `\renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}{}`, both did not work.

Comment: Related: [What does `\nop` mean and how to use it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109039/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following redefinition:

```
\renewcommand\lstinputlisting[2][]{}
```